# Android Beginner: How can I build a dynamic Hello World app?

Tags: android, text, dynamic, mobile

First things, first, I'm just starting with Android Application Development and would like to make a basic starter app. I have a Hello World app which will display the text Hello World when a button is pressed, but I would like to know how I can include a text box for a name, so the user can enter their name and then have the app say hello to them when they press the button.

Any help would be appriciated because I haven't a clue if I'm honest, I'm still figuring out what most of the code does but creating simple apps like this help me further my understanding.

Thank you,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the text box you'll probably want to use a [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). Make sure to insert it into your layout xml and give it a name you can reference, like `nameTextBox` or something. It should look something like

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nameTextBox" android:layout_width="match_parent"></EditText>
```

Then when your activity runs, make sure to put it into a variable like you probably did your `HelloButton`. So

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
nameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTextBox);
```

Then when the user clicks the button go ahead and grab whatever is in the `nameBox`. If you're using a `ClickListener` for your button this would go inside the `OnClick` method, just before you print out the text.

```
String name = nameBox.getText().toString(); // Inherits toString from CharSequence
// code to display concatenate and display your hello string goes here
```

Comment: getText() returns an Editable so you need to convert that to a String using toString() for example

Comment: @matsjoe Right, I was thinking casting would work for some reason. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look at the samples provided by google on the android developer page.

http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Look how things are done there and use that to make your own

Comment: Better still, follow the first four [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial). They'll teach you what to do, rather than leave you guessing at sample code.

Comment: ah I haven't seen that tutorials before didn't even know they exist.